# como modificar una fecha de base de datos sql con moment js

Tags: javascript, mysql, momentjs

Necesito de multiples filas ver cuales tienen la fecha del dia y hacer operaciones con dichas filas estoy usando momentjs quisiera saber como puedo modificar el formato de sql con momento js y luego compararlo con moment().format('YY-MM-DD') hice este codigo pero me modifica los valores de la base de datos a fechas que no son

```js
const payments = await Payment.findAll().catch( err =>{ return res.status(500).send({err:err}) })
            if(payments && payments.length > 0){
                let now = moment().format('YY-MM-DD');

                payments.forEach( pay => {
                    if(moment(pay.createdAt).format('YY-MM-DD') != now){
                        console.log(moment(pay.createdAt).format('YY-MM-DD'),"!!"); 
                    }

                    if( moment(pay.createdAt).format('YY-MM-DD') == now ){
                        console.log(moment(pay.createdAt).format('YY-MM-DD'),"==");
                    }
                }); 
                console.log(now,"now");
            }
```

esto me devuelve en consola

```
21-12-07 !!
21-12-07 !!
21-12-06 !!
21-12-05 !!
21-12-07 !!
21-12-08 now
```

y los valores de la fechas de mi bd son estos [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo haría con código SQL, `date_format("campo_tu_fecha", "%d/%m/%Y")` o algo parecido.